How to handle on failure call back in AWS Step Function
I have a step function workflow that needs to trigger the following sequence: Lambda1 → AnotherStep → Lambda2. If everything goes well, I want to update the status in the database at the end. If any failure occurs, I need to update the status in the database to 'error,' including the payload

I tried to use Choice feature after each task to check whether job status failed or not and created this complex diagram.

I am sure there will be easy way to implement this but I am not sure how. Thanks in advance.

You're best bet here is likely to decouple the status persistence using an event-driven approach. You can do this using EventBridge and the Execution Status Change events that Step Functions emits for Standard Workflows (which I can see you are using from the diagram above).
This helps you to avoid mixing the auditing logic you want with the business logic of this workflows (the complexity you are referring to). The other benefit of doing this is that you can leverage this to record status for other workflows as well (avoiding the need to repeat this auditing logic).
Your status handling workflow might look like this:
{
  "Comment": "A state machine to handle execution state change events.",
  "StartAt": "Update Status",
  "States": {
    "Update Status": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
      "OutputPath": "$.Payload",
      "Parameters": {
        "FunctionName": "<function>",
        "Payload": {
          "state_machine.$": "$.detail.stateMachineArn",
          "execution_arn.$": "$.detail.executionArn",
          "status.$": "$.detail.status",
          "input.$": "$.detail.input"
        }
      },
      "Retry": [
        {
          "ErrorEquals": [
            "States.ALL"
          ],
          "IntervalSeconds": 1,
          "MaxAttempts": 5,
          "BackoffRate": 2,
          "JitterStrategy": "FULL"
        }
      ],
      "End": true
    }
  }
}

And the EventBridge rule might look like this in CloudFormation (assuming you've defined the status tracking workflow as StateMachineRecordStatus and you want to record status from two state machines, StateMachine1 and StateMachine2.
  EventRuleRecordStatus:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      EventBusName: default
      EventPattern:
        source:
          - aws.states
        detail-type:
          - Step Functions Execution Status Change
        detail:
          status:
            - FAILED
            - TIMED_OUT
            - ABORTED
            - SUCCEEDED
          stateMachineArn:
            - !Ref StateMachine1
            - !Ref StateMachine2
      State: ENABLED
      Targets:
        - Id: Id22722964-9426-4a5d-8b62-41ebd8c1697e
          Arn: !Ref StateMachineRecordStatus
          RoleArn: !GetAtt ApplicationRole.Arn  

Also, that status handling state machine should work well as an Express Workflow, which will minimize the additional cost for this status recording.
